# Stub a readonly property in a baseclass

Tags: c#, unit-testing, microsoft-fakes

I have a class like this:

```
public class Customer : CustomerBase
{
    // internals are visible to test
    internal string GenString()
    {
        // this actually composes a number of different properties 
        // from the parent, child and system properties
        return this.InfoProperty.Name + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "something else"; 
    }
}

// this class is in a 3rd party library, but from metadata it looks like this
public class CustomerBase
{
    public Info InfoProperty { get; }
}
```

My test looks something like this:

```
public class Tests
{
    public void MyTest()
    {
        using (ShimsContext.Create())
        {
            // Arrange
            /* I shim datetime etc. static calls */

            Fakes.StubCustomer c = new Fakes.StubCustomer()
            {
                InfoProperty = new Info("Name") // <- Error here because it's readonly
            };

            // Act
            string result = c.GenString();

            // Assert
            Assert.AreEqual(result, "whatnot");
        }
    }
}
```

So my question is, how can I stub/shim the readonly property so that I can test this function?

Comment: Some thoughts - I would reconsider declaring private members as internal to make unit testing easier, if this is the actual case here. You could just use reflection to get to it. And second, why would you want to stub it? I mean, if you are already faking `DateTime` & `InfoProperty`, why not just let the thing concatenate?

Comment: You can use reflection to get around the access modifier (`private`) but it's not advisable. The property is *readonly* for some reason (it may be a derived value). You should find a way to set it indirectly (in a constructor? Through 2 or 3 other methods?).

Comment: @KeithPayne: It's a legit internal that I want to test, so that's not a worry. The problem is that stubbing InfoProperty (as seen in the example) doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

What about wrapping this getter in an ad hoc virtual method that could be overrided by a mock?

Eg:

```
public class Customer : CustomerBase
{
  // internals are visible to test
  internal string GenString()
  {
    // this actually composes a number of different properties 
    // from the parent, child and system properties
    return InfoPropertyNameGetter() + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "something else"; 
  }

  public virtual string InfoPropertyNameGetter(){
    retrn this.InfoProperty.Name;
  }
}

Mock<Customer> mock = new Mock<Customer>();
mock.Setup(m => m.InfoPropertyNameGetter()).Returns("My custom value");
```

It would look a bit like the `Introduce Instance Delegator` pattern described in [Working effectively with legacy code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131177052)